# Select most searched keyword from MySql group by q and user_id

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I want to show most searched keyword in my website. my search log table is this:

| id | user_id | q |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | shoes |
| 2 | 2 | cover |
| 3 | 1 | phone |
| 4 | 3 | shoes |
| 5 | 3 | shoes |
| 6 | 3 | cover |
| 7 | 4 | shoes |

I write this query to get unique search q and show them sort by repeat time:

```
SELECT `q`, COUNT(`q`) AS `value_occurrence` FROM search_queries GROUP BY q ORDER BY `value_occurrence` DESC
```

but there is an issue, if some one search `shoes` for 10 time, my query's `value_occurrence` increase 10, but i want just count any keyword for any single `user_id` just one time.

i try this but it's not correct way:

```
GROUP BY q,user_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must count the distinct `user_id`s:

```
SELECT q, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS value_occurrence 
FROM search_queries 
GROUP BY q 
ORDER BY value_occurrence DESC
```

Comment: Yes! , Great solution